# Brother Printer Error Codes - E58 on HL7050

Tags: printing

Does anyone have a list of the Brother Printer Error Codes, and/or know what E58 refers to?

I support quite a few Brother printers, but this is the fist time I've come across this one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

All the ERROR ### codes for this printer are "Call service" messages:

> Turn off the printer. Wait a few
>   seconds, then turn it on again. If
>   this does not clear the problem, call
>   your dealer or a Brother-authorized
>   service representative.

This is in the printer's user guide, available as a PDF at the [Brother Solutions Centre for the HL7050](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/faq/faq_top.htm?reg=us&prod=hl7050_all&c=us&lang=en) under the Manuals tab

Answer (score 1):

The E58 Service call message relates to:

> Malfunction of TR
>   Release Motor

and/ or

> Connection failure of TR Release
>   Motor connector and TR Release Motor
>   sensor

From the HL5070 service manual

Answer (score 0):

It's a "Do a power cycle and when the problem persits, call Support" error.